# Colour not rendering properly Pie Chart d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am working on a pie chart today in D3 (fun!).

Alright, the issue I am having is the colours aren't being assigned properly.

Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zh34ud25/5/

Most(?) relevant code:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#71b2b9", "#dcdcdc"]);

color.domain(d3.keys(dataUnbilledRevenue[0].values[0]).filter(function(key) { 
  if (key === 'Unbilled_Revenue'
   || key === 'Billed_Revenue') {
      return key
  }
}));


// This returns the data into two separate objects which can be graphed.
// In this case, Amount and Quantity.
var datasets = color.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    values: dataUnbilledRevenue.map(function(d) {
      return {
        Value: +d.values[0][name]
      };
    })
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple, doing this will give the colors to pie:

```
   pieValues.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr('class', 'pie-point')
       .style("fill", function(d) {
         return color(d.data.name)

       })
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/csLqctq1/)

Comment: Interesting. But then the hover doesn't work. Boo.

Alright, I can see if I can work around that.